# How to access the dynamically generated options via javascript in dropdownlist in codebehind c#?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery

Ok, I'm actually using a jQuery plugin, to be specific, it's the DualListBox.

I'm trying to loop on the options added on the second box to get their values, but the codebehind cannot detect it. How will I solve this? Does anybody encountered same problem from the past?

Comment: Use a `HiddenField`, when user selects an option, set value of that option to `HiddenField` using javascript. On the server you can get value of the `HiddenField`. I usually do this way :)

Comment: According to the DualListBox documentation the default behaviour is to select all the options in the second list box before posting so you *should* be able to get the values.  To disable the default behaviour you have to set the plug-in option `selectOnSubmit` to false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is because server side does not know what is populated on client side (typically that's not part of view state).

The workaround for this is

1. EITHER use hidden field which you can populate on change of drop down (client side) and retrieve it on server
2. OR you can obtain value Request.Form["CONTROL_NAME_HERE"] on post back

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the help, i think i'll go on using the first option. :)

Comment: Yes, it's more suitable. But make sure you have reset/set value of hidden field especially if there are multiple drop downs associated with each other.

Comment: Please do mark it as answer or vote helpful if it helps.